# How to create a smooth graph with sklearn,neighbors KernelDensity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I have 90 data points of X, whose size is 90 x 1 np array
I want to draw a KDE plot so that on the x-aixs, it is the magnitude of X and on the Y-axis, the Gaussian Probability.
I want the plot that is a smooth line with all 90 points included in the plot(not really included since it is a KDE...but you get the idea).

I have a code line below.

```
kde = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", bandwidth=0.01).fit(X)
log_dens = kde.score_samples(X)
axs2[0].scatter(X[:, 0], np.exp(log_dens))
```

This produces a graph that is a good looking scatter plot... but not a smooth KDE line that I want to.

I have tried

```
axs2[0].fill()
axs2[0].plot()
```

But both of them with no avail.
How to do this?

Comment: maybe you could try `seaborn`'s `kdeplot` (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)